# Next Project Environmental Variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I am working on a Next project now (only UI design )and I was provided with a .env.local file which contains the envt variables to access authorized pages. But even after adding it to the root directory of the project, I am still directed to the login page and react also complains of Hydration eorr which I find to be extremely strange.
Do you have any advice on how to resolve this because if not there is no way to gain any progress T__T

The.env.local file is a list of the MongoDB envt variables.
Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

```
    Call Stack
    checkForUnmatchedText
    node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (9647:0)
    didNotMatchHydratedTextInstance
    node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (11394:0)
    prepareToHydrateHostTextInstance
    node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (12606:0)
    completeWork
    node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22232:0)
    completeUnitOfWork
    node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (26596:0)
    performUnitOfWork
    node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (26568:0)
    workLoopSync
    node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (26466:0)
    renderRootSync
    node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (26434:0)
    performConcurrentWorkOnRoot
    node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (25738:0)
    workLoop
    node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js (266:0)
    flushWork
    node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js (239:0)
    MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline
    node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js (533:0)
    after adding the .env.local file at the root
```

I have checked the .gitignore file as well and .env.local is inside. Is there a way to access the protected page so I can quickly start the UI design already.

Comment: Please share more details. Provide minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with next, are you sure all of your env variables start with `NEXT_PUBLIC` like `NEXT_PUBLIC_VARIABLENAME`?

[Next Link](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables)